# Android button layout - 5 buttons and a badge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I've used a lot of hours trying to imperfect my xml design so it will work on a phone and a tablet, both horizontal- and vertical orientation.

[Picture of current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZyJm.png)

On the 4 first items it's TableRows and the last is RelativeLayout because of the badge, Can anyone help me redesign it so they all look the same and it looks good on phone and tablet. What is the best way to arrange buttons without using fixed width etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:weightSum="5.3"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/painter"
            android:id="@+id/btn_painter"
            android:background="@drawable/painter_button_bg"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/workman"
            android:id="@+id/btn_workman"
            android:background="@drawable/workman_button_bg"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/vvs"
            android:id="@+id/btn_vvs"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/vvs_button_bg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/edit_list"
            android:id="@+id/btn_editlist"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_button_bg"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/badge_layout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout_item_count2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sendlist"
                    android:text="@string/send_list"
                    android:background="@drawable/send_button_bg"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.70"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/badge_notification_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout_item_count2"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.) add this in gradle file 
 compile 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'

2) add this in layout file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

    <com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/myFlowLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|top">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>

</LinearLayout>

3) add this in main activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText myEditText;

    FlowLayout myFlowLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

        myFlowLayout = (FlowLayout)findViewById(R.id.myFlowLayout);

        myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    createBadget(myEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"DONE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private void  createBadget(String str) {

        FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_badget, null);

        params.setMargins(14, 14, 14, 14);

        child.setLayoutParams(params);

        final TextView tv = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.badge_tv);
        tv.setText(str);

        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        mylist.add(str);

        myFlowLayout.addView(child,myFlowLayout.getChildCount()-1);
        System.out.println("arraylist ::"+mylist);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that maybe you could work with.  It's direct copy of the layout of my app where I have a play, pause, and stop button, that evenly fills the entire width of any display, no matter the size.  `

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_buttonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_play"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
        android:contentDescription="@string/play"
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_pause"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pause"
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_stop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stop"
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

You could add this between each button if you want a line break

```
<View
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:background="@color/background"
        />
```

Comment: That did not help :(